# Do mango seed kernels contain Vitamin B-12?

Tags: nutrition, vitamins

There are a lot of blog posts and video channels claiming that mango seed kernels contain a high level of vitamin B12. I could find only one academic paper that claimed this:

[Some nutrients and antinutrients contents of mango (Magnifera indica) seed](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/some-nutrients-and-antinutrients-contents-of-mango-Fowomola/793296a6d895ad9c661f67a5969acbfe7b37f742) - M.A. Fowomola, 2010, African journal of Food sciences

They claim 0.12 mg of Vitmain B12 per 100 g of Mango seed! If true, it would be a major source of Vitamin B12, especially for vegans and vegetarians.

How reliable is this claim? Although this is published in a journal, I am sceptical because:

- Vitamin B-12 can only be synthesized by some archaea and bacteria. It is unclear how mango seed could contain such high levels of this substance.
- the journal isn't that well known to me

Note: For anyone stumbling upon this, the same paper suggests soaking and boiling, roasting and boiling, or other forms of treatment to reduce anti-nutrients in mango seeds, before human consumption:

> Low
> levels of antinutrients observed in mango seed suggested
> that it is less toxic and it will not adversely affects live
> stocks if incorporated in their feeds. The works of
> Ravindran and Sivakanesan (1996), Farag (2001) and
> Agunbiade and Olanlokun (2006) had earlier shown
> that soaking and boiling,autoclaving for 30 min plus
> irradiation up to 20 kGy and roasting and boiling
> drastically reduced the antinutrional factors present in
> mango seed kernels respectively, thereby improved their
> nutritional qualities.

Comment: United States Department of Agriculture, Agricultural Research Service, 2018). says 0.00. I do have full access to the publication, so can't verify.